# solidify modifier has changed the original index

Tags: python

I use solidify modifier to give my model a thickness with python

after that I want to select the new verts create by the modifier.

I recorded the vert index before using the modifier, select the vert by index and invert

but the index may has changed, selected verts scattered

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
origin_index = [v.index for v in bm.verts]

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="Thickness", type='SOLIDIFY')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Thickness"].solidify_mode = 'NON_MANIFOLD'
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Thickness"].thickness = 1
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Thickness", single_user=True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

for i in origin_index:
    bm.verts[i].select_set(True)
```

Comment: Hello, maybe you can store a list with the selected vertices coordinates, then loop over the new vertices and select by coordinate.

Comment: @Gorgious o, thanks Although there may be slight changes in coordinates after applying the modifier, storing it only requires retaining two decimal places